# Not getting value for select value in app.post in form for HTML/JS application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I am creating a form in which few valies are coming from DB and than i am updation the flag from 1 to 0 using select but app.post response body is not showing any data below is the code ... And there is one other method app.get from which i am showing data.

HTML(.HBS file ):-

```
<form action="/auth/access" method="POST"> 
        <div class="table-data">
<h4 style = "position:relative; left:80px; top:2px;">Showing user </h4>

<br>

    <table style = "position:relative; background-color:white ;width : 1430px;left:5px;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>User Email</th>
            <th>User Name</th> 
           <th>Approval Flag</th>
        </tr>
       
       <div>
    {{#each accessData}}
    {{#if value.Flag}}
               <tr>
            <td>{{value.User_Email}}</td>
            <td>{{value.User_Name}}</td> 
          <td><select name="approval" id="approval">
    <option value= "1">No</option>
    <option value= "0" >Yes</option>
  </select></td>
        </tr>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
        </table>
        <br>
        </form>
        <form action="/auth/access" method="POST">
        <button style = "position:relative; left:80px; top:2px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

app.js:-

```
app.post('/auth/access',async function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
/
});
```

Comment: your submit button is on other form. Move it inside your form.

Comment: @Mehrwarz Thanks do you know how can i send value.User_Email also in req.body